# Kernel panic: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily

Tags: kernel-panic

I am having repeated kernel panics. I'm hoping someone can give me a clue. the panic looks exactly the same each time. I've pasted the entire .panic below, but here are some relevant parts,

```
  Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
     com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.7.3)[1D668879-BEF8-3C58-ABFE-FAC6B3E9A292]@0xffffff7f8d844000->0xffffff7f8d868fff
     com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform(1.7)[D49DC2E0-97DF-32E6-A8ED-7A12EF1AA51B]@0xffffff7f8e542000->0xffffff7f8e599fff
        dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[A35915E8-C1B0-3C0F-81DF-5515BC9002FC]@0xffffff7f8dd85000
        dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.7.3)[1D668879-BEF8-3C58-ABFE-FAC6B3E9A292]@0xffffff7f8d844000
```

and

```
last loaded kext at 15475770759096: com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    3.6.0b1 (addr 0xffffff7f8f4d7000, size 229376)
last unloaded kext at 14656042905324: com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController   1.0.2b1 (addr 0xffffff7f8e628000, size 24576)
```

I've run the apple diagnostic tool and it comes up clean. As you can see I have no kernel extensions, and I actually have very little software actually installed.

Thanks ...

```
Interval Since Last Panic Report:  12073 sec
Panics Since Last Report:          1
Anonymous UUID:                    07A92488-9AD3-5A2A-B1A2-19DFBB6B38D0

Tue Jul 16 16:30:21 2013
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff800d2b7e95): Kernel trap at 0xffffff800d645ca8, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0x0000000000000000, CR3: 0x0000000075ddf08e, CR4: 0x00000000001606e0
RAX: 0x0000000000000000, RBX: 0xffffff802def3f00, RCX: 0x0000000000000000, RDX: 0xffffff80399aab00
RSP: 0xffffff81ce121f40, RBP: 0xffffff81ce121f40, RSI: 0x0000000000000000, RDI: 0x0000000000000000
R8:  0xffffff802e09c000, R9:  0x0000000000000008, R10: 0x000000010338ab20, R11: 0x00000001037cd040
R12: 0x0000000102d3ade0, R13: 0x0000000000000001, R14: 0x00000000000000a2, R15: 0x0000000000000001
RFL: 0x0000000000010082, RIP: 0xffffff800d645ca8, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000000
Fault CR2: 0x0000000000000000, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x0

Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff81ce121be0 : 0xffffff800d21d626 
0xffffff81ce121c50 : 0xffffff800d2b7e95 
0xffffff81ce121e20 : 0xffffff800d2cd4dd 
0xffffff81ce121e40 : 0xffffff800d645ca8 
0xffffff81ce121f40 : 0xffffff7f8d845865 
0xffffff81ce121f50 : 0xffffff7f8e548ead 
0xffffff81ce121f60 : 0xffffff7f8e55050b 
0xffffff81ce121f80 : 0xffffff800d2b74cf 
0xffffff81ce121fd0 : 0xffffff800d2cd698 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.7.3)[1D668879-BEF8-3C58-ABFE-FAC6B3E9A292]@0xffffff7f8d844000->0xffffff7f8d868fff
         com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform(1.7)[D49DC2E0-97DF-32E6-A8ED-7A12EF1AA51B]@0xffffff7f8e542000->0xffffff7f8e599fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[A35915E8-C1B0-3C0F-81DF-5515BC9002FC]@0xffffff7f8dd85000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.7.3)[1D668879-BEF8-3C58-ABFE-FAC6B3E9A292]@0xffffff7f8d844000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: java

Mac OS version:
12D78

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 12.3.0: Sun Jan  6 22:37:10 PST 2013; root:xnu-2050.22.13~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 3EB7D8A7-C2D3-32EC-80F4-AB37D61492C6
Kernel slide:     0x000000000d000000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff800d200000
System model name: MacBookPro10,1 (Mac-C3EC7CD22292981F)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 15475773984774
last loaded kext at 15475770759096: com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    3.6.0b1 (addr 0xffffff7f8f4d7000, size 229376)
last unloaded kext at 14656042905324: com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController   1.0.2b1 (addr 0xffffff7f8e628000, size 24576)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    3.6.0b1
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    4.9.6
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 1.8
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.1.3f3
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.60
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.5.10
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.0.6d1
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.12.87
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    122
com.apple.GeForce   8.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD4000Graphics   8.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   2.3.7fc4
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   2.3.7fc4
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHCIControllerUSBTransport  4.1.3f3
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.3d0
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   614.20.16
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.6.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.3.0
com.apple.driver.ApplePolicyControl 3.3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferCapri 8.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.1.11
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  237.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 237.1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 34
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    5.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  2.5.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   5.5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXHCI   5.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   1.5
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.6
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 196.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   4.0.39
com.apple.security.quarantine   2
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   196.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.2b1
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.5
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter   1.8.9
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIUpAdapter   1.2.6
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  10.0.6
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.5.5
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   86.0.4
com.apple.nvidia.gk100hal   8.1.0
com.apple.NVDAResman    8.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily 30.14
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 2.3.7fc4
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   1.8.9fc11
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.6
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.1.3f3
com.apple.iokit.AppleBluetoothHCIControllerUSBTransport 4.1.3f3
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 2.3.7fc4
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 2.3.7fc4
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   522.4
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.11d0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.3.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.3.7
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.4d2
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.3.0d51
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.11d0
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.3.7
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    1.8.9
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    1.8.9
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 1.2.6
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 237.3
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  5.2.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   5.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  5.2.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    1.6.3
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 2.2.6
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 5.5.5
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.3.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 5.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    1.7
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 1.8.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  220.2
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  7
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 345
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  28.21
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  1.7
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.7.3
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
System Profile:
Model: MacBookPro10,1, BootROM MBP101.00EE.B03, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.7 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.3f35
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000, Intel HD Graphics 4000, Built-In, 512 MB
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M, NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M, PCIe, 1024 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D5434314753364D465238432D50422020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D5434314753364D465238432D50422020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xEF), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.16)
Bluetooth: Version 4.1.3f3 11349, 2 service, 18 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Display Ethernet, Ethernet, en2
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
PCI Card: Apple 57761-B0, sppci_ethernet, Thunderbolt@13,0,0
PCI Card: pci11c1,5901, sppci_ieee1394openhci, Thunderbolt@14,0,0
PCI Card: pci12d8,400e, sppci_usbopenhost, Thunderbolt@12,0,0
PCI Card: pci12d8,400e, sppci_usbopenhost, Thunderbolt@12,0,1
PCI Card: pci12d8,400f, USB Enhanced Host Controller, Thunderbolt@12,0,2
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SD512E, 500.28 GB
USB Device: hub_device, 0x8087  (Intel Corporation), 0x0024, 0x1a100000 / 2
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in), apple_vendor_id, 0x8510, 0x1a110000 / 3
USB Device: hub_device, 0x8087  (Intel Corporation), 0x0024, 0x1d100000 / 2
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2512, 0x1d180000 / 3
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub, 0x0a5c  (Broadcom Corp.), 0x4500, 0x1d181000 / 5
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller, apple_vendor_id, 0x8286, 0x1d181300 / 8
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad, apple_vendor_id, 0x0262, 0x1d182000 / 4
USB Device: hub_device, apple_vendor_id, 0x9127, 0x40100000 / 2
USB Device: Nexus 4, 0x18d1  (Google Inc.), 0x4ee1, 0x40120000 / 7
USB Device: hub_device, 0x058f  (Alcor Micro, Corp.), 0x6254, 0x40130000 / 6
USB Device: Evoluent VerticalMouse 4, 0x1a7c, 0x0191, 0x40131000 / 8
USB Device: Apple Thunderbolt Display, apple_vendor_id, 0x9227, 0x40170000 / 5
USB Device: Display Audio, apple_vendor_id, 0x1107, 0x40140000 / 4
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Display), apple_vendor_id, 0x1112, 0x40150000 / 3
```

Comment: I really don't think anyone is going to find the cause by way of the log. It might help more if you describe what you are doing when the panic occurs. And perhaps try yourself to find a certain task that is always present during the critical failure.

Comment: bro,did u solve your problem?
i got the same question and don't know how to do.....

Comment: almost 10 years later, the problem persist  https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/678644?page=12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Responding to myself.

In this case, the problem was my apple cinema display. I don't know the details, but the system only crashed while connected, and I verified a brand new out of the box mac crashed on the display as well. A new display solved the problem for me.

I appreciate the troubleshooting info, but i'd already done the obvious. I uninstalled all kernel extension and almost all software. It wasn't a software issue (well, not a 3p software issue).

Answer (score 0):

The issue of repeated panics is serious, and there are no utilities than can diagnose them. But there are steps the user can take.

Apple has a support page, [About Kernel Panics](http://support.apple.com/kb/ts3742).

Macworld has an article, [How to Troubleshoot a Kernel Panic](http://www.macworld.com/article/2027201/how-to-troubleshoot-a-kernel-panic.html).

While posting panic logs may seem helpful, in reality not many can read them. Instead, post the details of hard- and software and what you are doing when they happen. Specifically, your log indicates that a java program was running at the time of the crash. Can you shut down java or dig into what might be happening when these repeated crashes happen?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this error today (com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily 1.2.0) using Disk Warrior Boot disk>Rebuild feature. I have no idea what exactly was wrong (due to the fact that kernel panic logs don't make any reliable sense to me) but there were errors/discrepancies on my drive. The drive is healthy with 12,000 poh.

I also ran a file check with Disk Warrior. Boots good now.