# macOS Panic: ANS2 Recoverable Panic

Tags: macos, kernel-panic

In the past week my iMac (latest Intel iMac) has crashed several times with the exact same reason. I have nothing attached to it except a TimeMachine drive. A few months ago I upgraded RAM from 32GB to 64Gb, I bought the same make and model (HMA82GS6DJR8N-VK is the part number for all 4 modules).

The top of the window says bridge OS which isn’t the typical [kernel panic on macOS seen here previously](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/96549/5472).

[image]

```
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xfffffff00d65f1fc): ANS2 Recoverable Panic - assert failed: [1404]:NVMe Driver Command 
timeout, DW0 0xb2002, arg2 0x1590000, arg3 0x60000000 - power(13)
assert failed: [1404]:NVMe Driver Command timeout, DW0 0xb2002, arg2 0x1590000, arg3 0x60000000
RTKit: RTKit_iOS-1827.140.2.release - Client: 
t8012.release-AppleStorageProcessorANS2-1274.100.6~1055~1274.100.6~1055
```

I posted the entire message here https://pastebin.com/EzCix1Xd

I also did NVRAM and SMC reset yesterday and this happened again today. It happens randomly, yesterday after waking up the machine from sleep, today in the middle the work.

This same crash is also confirmed on quite a few [16 inch MacBook Pro with intel chips](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP809?locale=en_US).

Is there any documentation on, software or or repair fixes likely to return these to stable operation?

Comment: I thought it's because of the TimeMachine disk, but it happened without it too.

Comment: In my case, the first line states something with "low wA":
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xfffffff0113d8744): ANS2 Recoverable Panic - assert failed: [14083]:low wA f4 i655593 s1291353 n16 d0 w1.9 tGC15 tL30, d:0x22002, a2:0x3610003, a3:0x60000000 - power(13)

Comment: Can you link to your exact model year Intel Mac? Latest could be the pro or several versions of intel 27 or the latest 24 inch one

Comment: I have this exact same issue with a 16" MacBook Pro 2019.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was getting exactly this problem on my MacBook Pro 16" 2019. My machine was crashing every day. I was able to solve this problem by disabling Spotlight indexing on my Bootcamp volume. In System Preferences, open the Spotlight pane. Click on the "Privacy" tab, and press the "+" button at the bottom. Add the Bootcamp volume to the list of volumes that Spotlight should avoid searching. My machine has not crashed from this panic once since making this change.

In MacOS Ventura, disabling Spotlight access to a folder is done through the "Spotlight Privacy..." button at the bottom of the "Siri and Spotlight" category in System Settings.

Thank you to @Tinh Anh for the solution.
https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/448523/470938

Comment: it worked for me too

Comment: Oh my. Mine has been crashing every night for months and I just stumbled onto this answer. I'm trying it right away and I'll see if it works. 

Answer (score 4):

Updated answer based on mdwelsh & Tinh Anh. There is no Bootcamp panel in System Preferences. Instead go to **System Preferences** > **Spotlight** > **Privacy Tab** > '**+**' and select your Bootcamp volume.

So far I haven't had a crash. So thanks to the mdwelsh & Tinh Anh for the guidance.

Comment: Thanks! Edited my answer, sorry for the typo!

Answer (score 2):

If you use bootcamp install Window! Went to system settings and excluded bootcamp drive from spotlight indexing and that seemed to fixed the problem! No more kernel panics!

Comment: Your answer does not answer the problem as described. There is no mention of bootcamp in the OP.

Comment: This may be worth trying. I have the same kernel panic issue and do have Bootcamp with Windows.

Comment: okay, i'll try it and see if it helps.

Comment: This answer solved the problem for me. Before making this change, my Mac was crashing every day with the panic described by OP. After making this change, my Mac has not crashed once -- it has been more than a week. Thank you @Tinh Anh for this answer!

Answer (score 0):

The panic seems to indicate that you have a problem with the SSD storage on your Mac.

I would advise immediately checking that your TimeMachine backups are okay. Then proceed to do an Apple Hardware Test to check if it reports SSD errors.

If not, I would boot it up in Recovery Mode and see if you can provoke the error to happen there.

If your computer is still covered by Apple, I would call Apple Support to get them to examine the hardware to see if you can get a replacement.

Comment: I have the same problem as OP, and I immediately thought this could have to do with the SSD as well. I have run the full hardware diagnostics and it has not come back with any problems. So it could be a hardware issue, but given that other people have started reporting this issue at the same time, it seems likely to me to be an OS bug.

Comment: I would not expect the full hardware diagnostics to find this problem necessarily. I still suspect this is a hardware issue, and I would call up Apple to get it fixed. It cannot be a macOS bug - if it is a software bug, it's in the T2 OS. If that is the case, then Apple would probably know that a large numbers of users complained about that, so that they can offer a fix.

Comment: Do you know of a good way to check whether the SSD hardware is faulty apart from Apple Diagnostics?

Comment: Depends on whether you mean in general or this particular error. For this particular error, I would start a simple tester that writes and reads to/from the drive to see if it is possible to provoke timeouts from the drive (and thus panics).

Answer (score 0):

disabling spotlight by adding my user folders into the privacy exclude section here System Preferences > Spotlight > Privacy Tab > '+'

i was getting random panic shut off's on clicks through the day, have gone through fresh installs, new ram, new SSD and was finally thinking it could be CPU problem, but after i looked into MDS and why it was hugging CPU i decided to untick all spotlight categories and add my main user folder into exclude here System Preferences > Spotlight > Privacy Tab > '+'

and guess what, i've not had a panic happen for an entire day so far (was getting at least 5 per hour)

Comment: I believe my case was because of an external monitor